# AngularJS 1 ui-router ignore the url changes triggered by hash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hash

I am extending an angularjs 1.5 project that uses the ui-router.

I need to store an array of parameters in the URL, and the parameters are changed constantly by the interface.

The app is set into html5Mode but each change of the hash triggers the app to try and find a route resulting in an unstable error being thrown.

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/dashboard');

    $stateProvider.
        // Main Layout Structure
        state('app', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/app',
            templateUrl: 'layout/app-body'
        }).
        // Dashboard
        state('app.dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'page/dashboard',
            controller: 'dashboardController'
        })..... etc etc
```

Is it possible to tell angular, or the ui-router to not act when a change is heard in the hash?

The controller that updates the hash just calls a simple replace state:

```
window.history.replaceState( '','', window.location.pathname + '#!test=true' );
```

Comment: Can you provide one of the URL change that break the app?

Comment: window.history.replaceState( '','', window.location.pathname + '#!test=true' );   called in a controller results  https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D

Comment: "I need to store an array of parameters in the URL";  first, that seems insecure, second, that would be `?`, not `#!`.

Comment: what no, how on earth is that insecure? this is like millions of other website that store things like map coords in the hash parameters and push into the history state allowing the back button to jump back through the map positions...

Comment: now you are describing something different.  you aren't "storing" parameters, you are trying to use the URL to pass parameters to a script on the page.  It *sounds like* your script you are trying to pass the values to is also a SPA application, and it is using `#!` in the same way angular is.  If that is the case, you would either want to change angular's `location.hash`, or change the hash the other app uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need set `anchor link`, for example `app/dashboard#value` - you can use `$location.hash`

`$location.hash('value');`

or for search parameters you can set optional parameters `?` -  `app/dashboard?test=value`

```
         state('app.dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'page/dashboard',
            controller: 'dashboardController',
            reloadOnSearch: false // do not reload on search param
        })
```

use `$location.search`

```
$location.search('test','value');
```